# How to remove an application update file?

Tags: applications, macos

I was updating Xcode and macOS High Sierra at the same time. The OS restarted and then Xcode was in update "paused" state. I tried but couldn't restart/resume it so I deleted the app hoping it would be fixed. Now the app is removed but I still have that icon in my Launchpad.

[image]

How can I remove this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try these steps:

1. Open Launchpad, press and hold the <kbd>Option</kbd> key. If you see a cross icon towards the top left side of the app (Xcode) icon, click on it.
2. Make sure that Xcode is **really** removed by checking for its absence in `/Applications` directory. Then restart your computer.

Either one of the two steps should remove the icon from the Launchpad. You can install Xcode afresh thereafter.

Comment: I did this before, it shows the cross button but clicking on it does nothing. I also restarted multiple times

Comment: Is Xcode deleted from `/Applications` directory and removed from Trash?

Comment: yes, it's removed and the trash is empty

Comment: You can try reinstalling Xcode from the App Store.